# Pop Up window is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC Views. 
   I want a pop up window after adding portal details,'Portal details' pop up is not working
    and also want to reload grid with data.

```
$("#addPortalDetails").dialog({
                            resizable: false,
                            autoOpen: true,
                            height: 140,
                            width: 300,
                            title:"Portal Details",
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    //reload grid with data
                                   }
                            }
                        });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To reload grid and  and popup window the code is

```
$("#addPortalDetails").dialog({
                            resizable: false,
                            autoOpen: true,
                            height: 140,
                            width: 300,
                            title: "Portal Details",
                            modal: true,
                            dialogClass: "noclose",
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                     $("#your_grid_id").setGridParam({datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }]);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Hi , If you are feeling this answer is correct please rate it so that it might help others also.